# Height of the Status bar Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hi I have bean creating a new Flutter project, but in some of screen sizes of the Status bar and the Toolbar has a space between themselves, how can I solve it?
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class MapPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MapPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Map"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try with wrapping with `SafeArea` and rebuild the app

Comment: I have tried that but the error persists

Answer (score 0):

It's the space for the cutout on device

You need to turn off Simulate display with cutout in developper settings, or edit your manifest app like showed here
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout